# How to obtain a LinkedIn token via Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, linkedin-api

I want to log in to my application via LinkedIn. This can be done via a call to Cloud.SocialIntegrations.externalAccountLogin() .

However, the function above needs a 'token' parameter. The 'token' is provided by LinkedIn by following the oauth flow(retrieve an authorization code, exchange of the Authorization Code for a Request Token).

Is there an easy way in titanium to obtain this token? I have investigated aaronksaunders's(https://github.com/aaronksaunders/clearlyinnovative.linkedIn) code, and searched on gitt.io. Or do we need to write all of this boilerplate code ourselves?

NOTE: At the moment, I don't want to proxy the call via a server(I prefer not to set up an SSL certificate, etc) and I don't have an appcelerator team or enterprise plan, so I can't use their node(arrow) backend to proxy these calls.

Additional question: is it sufficient to configure the iOS Bundle Identifiers(on the LinkedIn app settings page)? And do I need to use this 'iOS settings' application Id(also on the LinkedIn app settings page)?

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully finished my flow. Everything is explained in this blog post from Ramkumar M: http://shareourideas.com/2012/12/18/linkedin-connect-for-appcelerator-titanium/. The result is achieved by using a modified commonjs module version of the social.js library: https://gist.github.com/rampicos/4320296

This library has a very clean api, the whole flow is nothing more than:

```
var social = require('social');
var linkedin = social.create({
  consumerSecret : CONSUMER_SECRET,
  consumerKey : CONSUMER_KEY,
  site: 'linkedin'
});

linkedin.authorize(function(){
  //callback
});
```

I don't use the

```
Cloud.SocialIntegrations.externalAccountLogin()
```

because the login is done by the social.js library.

LinkedIn app: I have only configured the iOS bundle identifiers.